# Add Simple Panel for Saving/Loading

Tags: python, interface, add-on, panel

I currently have functions written for importing and exporting files which I'm running by doing something like this:

```
def loader(file0, file1, file2):
    function_to_load_file0(file0)
    function_to_load_file1(file1)
    function_to_load_file2(file2)

def saver(file0, file1, file2):
    function_to_save_file0(file0)
    function_to_save_file1(file1)
    function_to_save_file2(file2)

if __name__=='__main__':
    file_to_load_0 = "/path/to/file_0"
    file_to_load_1 = "/path/to/file_1"
    file_to_load_2 = "/path/to/file_2"
    #########################
    # When Loading
    #########################
    loader(
        file_to_load_0, 
        file_to_load_1, 
        file_to_load_2
    )

    # saver(
    #    file_to_load_0,
    #    file_to_load_1,
    #    file_to_load_2,
    # )
    #########################
    # When Saving
    #########################
    # loader(
    #     file_to_load_0, 
    #     file_to_load_1, 
    #     file_to_load_2
    # )

    saver(
        file_to_load_0,
        file_to_load_1,
        file_to_load_2,
    )
```

This is of course very hacky so I'd love to add in a simple panel with 3 text fields to enter the paths of the files to load, along with a simple button to pass all 3 fields to the `loader` function that gets executed and another button which passes all 3 fields to the `saver` function that gets executed.

I've struggled to find good documentation for what names blender expects for `bl_idname`, `bl_context`, etc. Can anyone offer any guidance or point me to resources that give an in-depth overview for adding simple UI elements? Here is my failed attempt at what I have so far:

```
class LoadSceneOperator(Operator):
    """Load Annotation Info"""
    bl_idname = "my.loader"
    bl_label = "Load file0, file, file2"
    file0 = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        default="/path/to/file0",
    )
    file1 = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        default="/path/to/file1",
    )
    file2 = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        default="/path/to/file2",
    )
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True
    
    def execute(self, content):
        #do stuff
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def draw(self, context):
        row = self.layout
        row.prop(self, "prop0", text="file0 Path")
        row.prop(self, "prop1 text="file1 Path")
        row.prop(self, "prop2 text="file2 Path")

class OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel(Panel):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_custom_panel"
    bl_label = "Custom Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return context

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object

        layout.label(text="Operators:")
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.operator(LoadSceneOperator.bl_idname, text="Load stuff", icon="CONSOLE")
      

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(LoadSceneOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LoadSceneOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: You can try and reverse-engineer default examples by going into the scripting editor > Templates > Python and there you'll have panel, operator, gizmo, nodes... simple examples.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do, but I'm stuck on the nomenclature for things like the class name being `OBJECT_PT_something`,  and the lists of valid values for things like `bl_idname`, `bl_label`, `bl_space_type`, etc

Comment: see See https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Addons/Guidelines/metainfo https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html and https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.bl_options for help on some of these things